# How to find relationships of removed column in PgAdmin4/

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have a psql rds aws database which is opened in my PgAdmin4 client.
And recently i removed one column from table in this database.
But now in my app i see error from backend `column student.scale does not exist`
I know it's because of me who deleted this column.
But how do i find out what is callind this column.
As in backend code there nothing what could call this column, so it's something in Database some relationship or key.
Is there way how i can find out it the easy way ?[image]

Comment: pgAdmin won't be able to help you there. You need to inspect your application's code to find the place where the old column is still used.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, this is actually what i cen't understand. 
I went through all the code in backend.
And i didn't find anything, where it could be used.
So I believe that it can be used somewhere in database, like some other columns may have relations with deleted one.
And i was just wondering if there are some way to find out it easy which column is trying to reach this removed column.

Comment: What is the application? Does it use an ORM? Add answers as update to question.  Best guess there is some 'magic' code that has not been informed that the table has had a column deleted.

Comment: It's serverles backend project on node.js.
But there are no any code which could use scale value in backend project.
And it uses ORM

Comment: So has the model in the ORM been modified to reflect the dropping of the column?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I looked at the model before i was removing column.
And after i removed column model doesn't seem to change

Comment: What is the ORM being used? Generally you have to do some sort of migration to get the ORM in a new state where the column has been removed.